# YouTube v3 API get video resolution

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Many videos are not 854px x 480px. For ex. this one is 854px x `376px`. How can I get this value using YouTube v3 API?

I tried this `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=V_ID&key=API_Key&part=snippet` but it doesn't give me what I want.

[image]

Comment: Look at the image you provide, it seems the `resolution` has been provide in the information window.

Comment: yes but how can I get it? what method? @bjiang

Comment: I think the info can get from `fileDetails` [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#fileDetails)

Comment: Sure go ahead and tell me the result:)

Comment: It says: This data can only be retrieved by the video owner. @bjiang

Comment: The request cannot access user rating information. This error may occur because the request is not properly authorized to use the \u003ccode\u003emyRating\u003c/code\u003e parameter. @bjiang

Comment: So I did some research, it seems that you cannot get the resolution data from youtube if you are not the video owner. I think the picture you uploaded is the details in the video player of a local file.